# Trigger FluentValidation Manually? Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, fluentvalidation

I am trying to use [Fluent Validation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/fluentvalidation.aspnetcore/) in Asp.net Core 2.0. I been able to hook it up as per the instructions but the problem is that as soon as it tries to go through the binding the validation rules are checked.

I don't want this automatic check to happen as I it returns back a different format then what I want for my errors, as I want to send all my errors back in the same way.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

One of the things you can do, to format your model errors in a particular way whether they've come from FluentValidation or in-built ModelBinding, is to add an `ActionFilterAttribute` into your middleware pipeline.

For example:
In your startup.cs

```
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add<ValidateModelFilter>();
       // ... plus all the other things you'd set up in your AddMvc options
    }).AddFluentValidation(fv=>fv.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties=true);
```

Then define your `ActionFilterAttribute` something like this:

```
public class ValidateModelFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid) {  return; }
        // There are model errors
        // iterate through each item in ModelState and 
        // pull out the errors/messages and present them however you like.
        // I'd use some kind of dedicated ErrorResult object

        actionContext.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(yourErrorResultObject)
    }

}
```